# How to run a command in vmware using vmrun, command is (echo %PROGRAMFILES%)

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware, vmrun

How to run a command in vmware using vmrun, command is (echo %PROGRAMFILES%) on the guest machine..
and the guest machine should return a value of the command result... how to do this??? please suggest

Answer (score 1):

I needed to do something similar and found this unanswered question.  Here's my solution.

```
@ECHO OFF

REM Set up abbreviations that we'll be using a lot.
SET VMRUN="C:\Program Files (x86)\VMware\VMware VIX\vmrun.exe" -T ws -gu Administrator -gp password
SET VMX="C:\Users\whoever\Documents\Virtual Machines\Windows\Windows.vmx"
SET GUEST_COMSPEC="C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe"

REM Tried to do this in one line, but couldn't figure out the quoting.
%VMRUN% CreateTempfileInGuest %VMX% >%TEMP%\GuestTmp.txt || GOTO :CantCreate
FOR /F "delims=;" %%F IN ( %TEMP%\GuestTmp.txt ) DO SET GTEMP=%%F

REM The batch file is a one-liner that echos the variable into a file.
REM It could be generated dynamically and copied to the guest
REM but I didn't want to complicate things any further.
%VMRUN% runProgramInGuest %VMX% %GUEST_COMSPEC% "/c C:\echo-ProgramFiles.bat %GTEMP%"
%VMRUN% CopyFileFromGuestToHost %VMX% %GTEMP% %TEMP%\GuestOut.txt
%VMRUN% DeleteFileInGuest %VMX% %GTEMP%

REM Do something with the result and delete the temp files.
TYPE %TEMP%\GuestOut.txt
DEL %TEMP%\GuestOut.txt %TEMP%\GuestTmp.txt
GOTO :EOF

:CantCreate
REM Provide details on any problems.
TYPE %TEMP%\GuestTmp.txt 1>&2
DEL %TEMP%\GuestTmp.txt
EXIT 100
```

And here's the batch file on the guest host.  As you can see, it's pretty simple.  I couldn't get redirection to work in runProgramInGuest (probably didn't experiment enough)
so I just pass the file as a command line argument.

```
@echo %PROGRAMFILES% >%1
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [vmrun](http://jaminquimby.com/joomla253/servers/121-vmware/vmware-server-2-0/314-vmware-server-20-vmrun-command-line) commands here. You need the Guest OS Command `runScriptInGuest`.

I have not checked the command , but it should look like this. Please verify it.

```
vmrun -T server -h https://xps:8333/sdk -u user -p mypassword -gu administrator -gp guestpaswd 
  runScriptInGuest "[Vol1] win2008-1/win2008-1.vmx" "echo %PROGRAMFILES%"
```

Comment: I have tried this and it doesnt work.. this is what I did below 
"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\VMware\\VMware Workstation\\vmrun.exe" -gu localname -gp password runScriptInGuest "C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Documents\\Virtual Machines\\Windows 8 32_ws\\Windows 8 32_ws.vmx" "C:\\windows\\system32\\cmd.exe" "/c echo %PROGRAMFILES%"

Comment: basically I need to run this command and capture the output of the command back in the host... I am not sure if this could be possible using vmrun commands

Comment: I can confirm that runScriptInGuest does not work properly in Windows (at least not what I'm using -- Windows 7 with VMWare 9). And yes, runProgramInGuest, executing a BAT file that was previously copied to the guest, is the solution, as demonstrated by samwyse's answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had to use runProgramInGuest
capture the output to a file
copy the file back to my host and use it
Thats the soln I used.